# Which movies mentioned by War Machine and Ant-Man actually support their point of view?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, time-travel, avengers-endgame

In a hilarious scene in *Avengers: Endgame*,

> Hulk is explaining how time travel works to War Machine and Ant-Man, who are shocked to learn that it doesn't work like it does in *Back to the Future*. Scott and Rhodes then take turns going through a whole list of movies to justify why they think going back and changing the past will cause changes to the present.

I don't remember all the movies they mention, but I remember one of them was

> *Bill and Ted's Excellent Adventure*. But that movie uses the model of *Immutable Time* - you can't ever change the past, and anything anyone does in the past turns out to be what already happened as part of a closed time loop all along. We see this even when the characters are interacting with their past selves!

Another movie mentioned was

> *A Wrinkle in Time*. I only saw that movie once and it was a while ago, but as I recall it didn't actually have any time travel at all.

So my question is,

> **What movies are listed by Scott and Rhodey, and which of them actually feature the trope of "Changes to the past cause changes to the present"?**

Comment: Bill and Ted is filled with paradoxical loops. Time certainly isn't immutable.

Comment: "Star Trek, Terminator, Timecop, Time After Time, A Wrinkle in Time, Somewhere in Time, Hot Tub Time Machine and Bill and Ted's Excellent Adventure, literally every movie ever made about time travel" :P

Comment: @Valorum maybe I'm using the wrong term, but my understanding of Fixed History/Immutable Time is that it doesn't preclude paradoxical loops, it just prevents any change in the past from actually altering the present. There's a great write-up of Bill and Ted specifically here: https://qntm.org/excellent

Comment: @MartianInvader - If it was impossible to change the past, Denomolos' plan wouldn't be any threat whatsoever. Rufus and the boys could just ignore him

Comment: @Valorum Rufus certainly seems to think he's doomed to fail: Rufus: "You won't get away with it." De Nomolos: "Time will tell." Rufus: "Time has told!"

Comment: There’s a difference between determinism and futility. The events of Bill and Ted turn out that way _because_ they choose to act, not in spite of their actions. They don’t have the choice not to act: the fact that they _did_ act is what makes their history deterministic. Basically, Denomolos failed to understand how time travel works, otherwise he would know there was no way to change history.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To answer this I'd like to refer to one of my favourite things on the Internet, [A Guide to SF Chronophysics](http://jbr.me.uk/chrono.html).

In the [Type Summaries](http://jbr.me.uk/chrono.html#d) section, it describes four general models of time travel:

1. Deterministic/Permanent
2. Elastic/Resilient
3. Overwriting/Contingent
4. Quantum-forking/Multi-divergent

*Avengers: Endgame* follows

> Type 4 (Quantum-forking), though it's significant to note that when a traveller returns to the future they return to their *original* timeline, and not to a timeline they have created due to branching.

Here's some of the movies mentioned by Rhodey and Lang and the Chronophysics model they follow:

- *Back to the Future*: most often interpreted as Type 3, but could also be Type 4
- *Star Trek*: Type 3 (occasionally Type 1 when it suits them)
- *Terminator*: *Terminator* (1) is Type 1, *Terminator 2: Judgment Day* revises that to Type 3, *Terminator 3: Rise of the Machines* revises that further to Type 2, *Terminator Genysis* kind of suggests Type 4 but doesn't actually make any sense... ultimately the franchise is a mess.
- *Timecop*: Type 3
- *Hot Tub Time Machine*: Type 3 and for some parts Type 1 (inconsistent)
- *Bill and Ted's Excellent Adventure*: Type 1

Others I'm not familiar enough to assign a type.

So to answer the original question, not all the movies listed by Rhodey and Lang actually support the idea that the present will be changed if you change the past. *Terminator* (1) and *Bill and Ted's Excellent Adventure* follow the Type 1 (Deterministic/Permanent) model where time travel to the past cannot alter the present.

However, none of them really follow the model that *Avengers: Endgame* does either...

> except (perhaps ironically) *Back to the Future* matches it most closely if you interpret it as Type 4.

However there are some important differences:

> In *Avengers: Endgame*, when a visitor to the past returns to the future, they return to their **original** timeline, not to any branched timeline they may have created. Possibly this is the purpose of the big time machine in Avengers HQ: it works as a beacon to bring the travellers back to their original timeline. In *Back to the Future*, a visitor returning to the future will arrive in a branched alternate timeline when attempting to return to the future, as Marty did when returning to 1985 from 1955 in the first movie. Travel to the past from a branched timeline can land you in an alternate timeline, as Marty and Doc did when travelling back from 2015 to alternate 1985. However Old Biff's return to 2015 after delivering the almanac to Young Biff contradicts this somewhat... he should have returned to an alternate 2015 he created. This may be why he phases out after arriving.

Also,

> in *Avengers: Endgame* a traveller **can** exist in a timeline that is not their original timeline if their past self is killed or ceases to exist, or if the events that sent them to the past are altered. In *Back to the Future* they cannot: in part one, once the timeline diverges to a future where Marty doesn't exist, he begins to phase out of that timeline. Notably the alternate 1985 that Marty and Doc visit still has an alternate Marty and Doc elsewhere that they do not meet, which allows them to exist in the alternate timeline.

Comment: All of the travellers were also wearing Time-GPS thing which might have guided them to their original timeline.

Comment: Actually I believe it’s the big time machine in Avengers HQ that’s the important part of returning to the original timeline. It acts as a beacon to return to when navigating the Quantum Realm. The Quantum/time GPS devices help locate that beacon.